# Material UI removing hover styles for inputs

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, styled-components

On the Material UI Text Inputs, there is a black border that appears when hovering over any input field. It honestly looks awful. How can I get rid of it?

I have this CSS content:

```css
& .MuiOutlinedInput-root {
    &.Mui-focused fieldset {
        border-color: green;
    }
    &:hover fieldset {
        border: none;
    }
}
```

which technically works, but now on hover it just removes to border entirely.

I've tried changing the *none* to *inherit* or *initial*, transparent, etc., but that also fails epically.

Comment: Will setting  `border-color: transparent` on hover works? or Can you create a small working snippet?

Comment: The `border-color` on hovering the input is already set as `border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87)`. You need to overwrite this to `border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.23)` which is the initial color.

Comment: @SaiManoj then when hovering and it is active the border disappears entirely. I don't want the border to go away, just not do any hovering

Comment: @SrishtiGupta, but then the hover would still be active. When active and has the green color if you hover over it you see the default styles. I really need to just turn off the hovering all together

Comment: @zazvorniki It would be good to share a working link for the existing code and the actual expectation is also not clear from the question.

Comment: @SrishtiGupta I would like to remove the hovering styles so when you hover nothing happens

Comment: What do you mean by *"removes to border"*?

Answer (score 0):

The feasible solution would be using the original border color as hover.

```
  "& .MuiOutlinedInput-root": {
    "& fieldset": {
      borderColor: "#E0E3E7" // this is the original border color
    },
    "&:hover fieldset": {
      borderColor: "#E0E3E7" // use the original border color on hover
    },
```

here is a working [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/upbeat-galileo-8fqx5z?file=/demo.js:494-687)